# Mysql ERROR 1064 (42000), database dump only created half the tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to dump an existing database onto my live server and I'm getting this error message.

What I have done so far:

- Created my website with django and applied migrations to mysql
- Opened up the database on mysql workbench, checked all the tables are there and working properly. (When I ran the website on the test server things were working properly so I know there is no issue there)
- Exported the local Mysql database as a single file, uploaded it onto the server via FTP
- Logged into my server via putty, opened up Mysql and got into the appropriate database then ran the following code:

  ```
  source /home/ec2-user/fta_sport_database_4.sql
  ```
- this successfully created 14 out of the 20 required databases but then I got this error:

  ```
  ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

  '(6) NOT NULL,
    `post_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `team_a_id` int(11) DEFAU' at line 10
  ```

I opened up the SQL textfile and this is the code that it seems to be struggling with:

```
CREATE TABLE `articles_post` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `post_slug` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `short_description` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` longtext NOT NULL,
  `headline_image` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_image` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `youtube_link` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `posted` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `post_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `team_a_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `team_b_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `headline_image_credit` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_image_credit` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `post_slug` (`post_slug`),
  KEY `articles_post_posted_2a82c6bc` (`posted`),
  KEY `articles_post_team_a_id_ef2d8ab7_fk_teams_team_id` (`team_a_id`),
  KEY `articles_post_team_b_id_10d6b1e5_fk_teams_team_id` (`team_b_id`),
  KEY `articles_post_post_category_id_54408756_fk_sports_sport_id` (`post_category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `articles_post_post_category_id_54408756_fk_sports_sport_id` FOREIGN KEY (`post_category_id`) REFERENCES `sports_sport` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `articles_post_team_a_id_ef2d8ab7_fk_teams_team_id` FOREIGN KEY (`team_a_id`) REFERENCES `teams_team` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `articles_post_team_b_id_10d6b1e5_fk_teams_team_id` FOREIGN KEY (`team_b_id`) REFERENCES `teams_team` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I didnt write any of the SQL textfile myself.

I have seen one solution that said the AUTO_INCREMENT needs to be 1 and not 2, but I changed that and it still didnt make any difference.

Comment: Version mismatch?

Comment: I did have the export mismatch but that was the first thing I fixed and I'm no longer getting that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating the table manually in the MySQL WorkBench, I believe the problem to be in some tables where it specified a DATETIME length of (6). In the table I created manually, it didnt accept DATETIME(6) but did accept DATETIME.

I think that is what was causing the problem.